# How can I use my usb-c equipped laptop in device (gadget) mode?

Tags: drivers, usb, kernel

I've recently "mousetrapped" my old trusty laptop and bought a new one. And it has a USB type C port on a side. I bought a USB OTG converter, so I can use it in HOST mode.

However it should be a dual-mode port, I could power a laptop using that port (if I had a correct PSU), and it can be turned into the host mode with a help of OTG cable.

Now I'm wondering - can I use this port to connect my laptop to other laptops and PCs as a device?
Because Linux has what's called "usb gadgets / gadget drivers" which Android phones and devices like single board computers can use to connect to let's say that exact laptop.

So,is it possible and how to configure any gadget to check this? Should I recompile the kernel or maybe this ports are half-working because nobody gonna try this. (But on the other hand ability to charge your laptop from your pc might be helpful).

PS. I've bought a cheap USB3-C "male" to USB2.0-A "male" cable, nothing happeds. (No new lines in lsusb on both sides of the cable).

Answer (score 2):

I have more questions than answers so bear with me.  I'll start with an answer, if your laptop can charge from USB-C then it is likely that the hardware supports gadget mode.  Another way to check is to plug the laptop into another computer using a USB-C to USB-C cable and see if the laptop appears on the other computer as a "USB billboard device", if it shows up like this then it likely can support other gadget modes.  Using a cheap USB-C to USB-A cable might explain why nothing happened, it might be that the cable doesn't have all the wires to support USB 3.x and that might be why it's not working.  I'm new to experimenting with USB gadgets too, and I haven't bothered to experiment with USB 2.0 cables, so I'm speculating quite a bit.

Now, some questions.  Which model of laptop are you using?  What do you mean by a "USB OTG converter"?  Which version/flavor/distro of Linux are you running?  It's likely some have better support for USB gadgets than others.  What kinds of gadget modes do you want from your laptop?  It appears to me that the most work has gone into serial, ethernet, and mass storage device gadgets.  What have you tried so far?  Personally I'm kind of spinning my wheels on my USB gadget experimentation since I had some hardware die on me after a power surge.  It could be a while before I get things back to normal.